# Logstash docker, how to stop send logs to stdout

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, logstash, stdout, amazon-cloudwatch

How to stop sending (using env variables) logs to the stdout?
I changed log_level to WARN, and yes I don't have INFO logs anymore, but I still receiving logs like this:

```
14:14:51 "namespace" => "AWS/ECS",
14:14:51 "period" => 300,14:14:51 "ServiceName" => "archive-logstash",
14:14:51 "@version" => "1",
14:14:51 "ClusterName" => "archive",
14:14:51 "minimum" => 0.4069010416666667,
14:14:51 "average" => 44.13362219887956,
14:14:51 "@timestamp" => 2020-03-30T14:14:42.420Z,
14:14:51 "aws_account" => "acc",
14:14:51 "maximum" => 71.2890625,
14:14:51 "sample_count" => 7.0,
14:14:51 "sum" => 308.9353553921569,
14:14:51 "unit" => "Percent",
14:14:51 "timestamp" => 2020-03-30T14:09:00.000Z,
14:14:51 "end_time" => 2020-03-30T14:14:39.000Z,
14:14:51 "metric_name" => "MemoryUtilization",
14:14:51 "start_time" => 2020-03-30T14:09:39.000Z
```

I don't need these logs, because Logstash will be in loop, will reading from that cloudwatch group together with other logs from fargate, an send it back again to the ELK.

Also this log format is totally unusable

I'm running Logstash in AWS fargate

Comment: What is your logstash pipeline configs? Those are not logs from Logstash, but outputs from pipelines, It seems that you have some outputs configured to `stdout`.

Comment: I'm using default logstash.conf file. In docker file I'm just installing few plugins, and aws-cli. Then docker entrypoint downloading logstash.conf from S3 bucket
`aws s3 cp s3://%s/%s.conf /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf && /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint`
only env I'm passing in is `XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED=false`. But I will look now how to handle pipeline logs. thx

Comment: Do you have something like `stdout { codec => rubydebug }` in the `output { .. } ` section of your translation file?

Comment: @WalterA you are right. I forgot that (facepalm).
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I wasn't sure so I first asked with a comment, but OP said this was the case)
You need to remove

```
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
```

in the

```
output { .. }
```

section of your translation file.

Comment: Please correct, so I can mark it as a best answer. 
I don’t need rubydebug, I already have it and because that all logs are directed to the stdout.. So I need to ***remove*** it.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/docker-config.html#_custom_images

So basically the logs go to stdout because of the default pipeline. The only thing you need to do is to remove this file of rewrite it, i.e. add for example add

```
RUN rm -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
```

to your Dockerfile